# How do I change the date format of date input fields in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, html

The date format for `<input type="date">` fields in my browser always show up using `MM/dd/yyyy` format. However not being American I prefer `dd/MM/yyyy`.

I have found several sources indicating this is dictated by the order of languages in "Language and input settings..." however this seems to have no effect. I have tried putting in, `en_UK` and `en_AU` above `en_US`. `en_US` cannot be removed from the list.

I am using Chrome Version 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit) on Linux Mint.

[image: Date input with 2nd of January 2016 in MM/dd/yyyy format]

How do I change the date format of date input fields in Chrome?

Comment: What is your OS long date format set as?

Comment: It looks like this was it. I had previously changed it but not restarted my system after changing, only the browser. Changing the system language to en_GB. Before I had language = en_US, and region = is, and had assumed date format came from region, not language.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot.

There is no a HTML specification to change this. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date

I think you still must use a jQuery plugin.

Comment: "the displayed date is formatted based on the locale of the user's browser"